# Elasticsearc-5.0.0 Weighted average

Tags: elasticsearch, average

I wanted to try weighted average on ES-5.0.0.
I tried something with json code:

```
GET ABC/xyz/_search 
{
  "aggs": {
    "myAggr": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "UrunNo",
        "order": { "weightedAvg": "desc"}
      },  
      "aggs": {
          "weightedAvg": { "avg" : { "script" : "[values: doc['BirimFiyat'].value, weights: doc['Adet'].value]" }}
       }    }  }  }
```

I have error:

```
  {"error": {
        "root_cause": [
          { "type": "parsing_exception",
            "reason": "Unexpected token VALUE_STRING [script] in [weightedAvg].",
            "line": 9,
            "col": 49
          } ],
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Unexpected token VALUE_STRING [script] in [weightedAvg].",
        "line": 9,
        "col": 49
      },"status": 400 }
```

What is the problem? or Is Weighted average possible on ES-5.0.0?

Comment: I guess the [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15731) is still open. Weighted avg is yet to be extended from aggs.